# for (var propertyName in object) vs for (propertyName in object)?

Tags: javascript

Which one of those two methods for iterating over the property names of an object are preferable?

```
for (var propertyName in object) {

}
```

vs.

```
for (propertyName in object) {

}
```

I know in the second example, propertyName becomes a global variable, which is something to avoid, so I guess the first one would be better, right?

Comment: Yes the first is better, though it's perfectly OK to declare the variables in a separate `var` statement too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question can be simplified to:

```
var a = 0; // option 1
b = 0;     // option 2
```

As you said:

- `var` in option 1 restricts the scope of the new variable; it also allows shadowing;
- option 2 will result in a new global variable, or assign the value `0` to any existing variable named `b` that's in scope.

Option 1 is thus indeed "better".

(However it's worth noting that the scope of `propertyName` in your first example will be of the enclosing **function**, *not* of the loop body or of any enclosing conditional block.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For exactly the reason you state. Why bleed data out of your loop if it isn't needed elsewhere?

Comment: But JavaScript scoping is such that the variable will be visible in the entire function in which that loop occurs.  JavaScript is significantly different than some other C-like languages in that regard.

Comment: I was slightly hesitant to downvote, but ultimately did because the answer is misleading: the variable "bleeds" out of the loop regardless.

Comment: Sure, but when declared in a function, hoisted only to function scope, not beyond.

Answer (score 1):

The first one. It is the equivalent of

```
var propertyName;
for (propertyName in object) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your particular usage, but I would say that for 99.9% of your first example is appropriate.  Leaving out the `var` keyword does not necessarily make `propertyName` global.  It can also refer to a previously defined variable in a parent scope.